# How to do sub-Array indexing

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array, filled with multiple value types, one of which is a sub-array, which in turn contains two smaller sub-sub-arrays:

```
array = ['b','t','66',[[' ',' '],[' ',' ']],'h']
```

When I run the program and request array index 3, which should contain both sub-sub-arrays, I get:

```
[[' '
```

instead of the entire array index 3 which should be:

```
[[' ',' '],[' ',' ']]
```

I am asking how this is occurring, and how I could extract `index[3]` in the above form.

Comment: http://codepad.org/pSUl3Db1

Comment: Nope, you must have misinterpreted output or something. It works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just messed up the single quotes so that the third element really is the string `"[[' '"`?

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. `array[3] # => [[" ", " "], [" ", " "]]`

Answer (score 3):

No, it's appearing as expected, no problem. See my executed program.

```
a=['b','t','66',[[' ',' '],[' ',' ']],'h']


puts a[3].inspect
```

Output

```
[[" ", " "], [" ", " "]]
```